# why doesn't my sorting code work?

Tags: c++, pointers

Write the definition of a function minMax that has five parameters . The first three parameters  are integers . The last two are set by the function to the largest and smallest of the values  of the first three parameters . The function does not return a value .

The function can be used as follows:

int  a=31, b=5, c=19 big, small; minMax(a,b,c,&big,&small); /* big is now 31 */ /* small is now 5 */

```
void minMax (int a, int b, int c, int *big, int *small) {
    if (a > b && a > c) 
        *big = a;
    else if (b>a && b>c)
            *big = b;
    else if (c>a && c>b)
            *big = c;

    if (a < b && a < c) 
        *small = a;
    else if (b<a && b<c)
        *small = b;
    else if (c<a && c<b)
        *small = c;
return;
}
```

Remarks:
     ⇒     Your function did not change the value of small. Make sure you are dereferencing it in your function.

Common Errors:
Make sure your if/else statements are correct.
Make sure you have semicolons at the end of each statement.
Make sure you are assigning the correct values to big and small.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome do you observe, what do you expect, and how do the two differ?

Comment: So have you tried the code?

Comment: Your function doesn't handle correctly the situations of 2 same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
void minMax(int x, int y, int z, int * big, int * small) 
{
    *big = x;   

    if (y > *big) 
    {
        *big = y;
    }

    if (z > *big) 
    {
        *big = z;
    }

    *small = x;

    if (y < *small)
    {
        *small = y;
    }

    if (z < *small)
    {
        *small = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could upvote the answer and give it a tick.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3 numbers `a`, `b` and `c` are all different, your code should work fine. But if 2 (or even all 3) values are the same, you will get an error, because you are always checking for "strictly greater than" and "strictly less than", that is, you are using `>` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=`. Try it with a=31, B=31, C=31 and you will see that you will neither assign a value to `*big` nor to `*small`.